# How to rewrite or simplify series equations

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you go from this equation:
$$\sum_{l=2}^n (n-l+1)(l-1)2$$
to this:
$$2\sum_{l=1}^{n-1} (n-l)l$$
and then to this:
$$ = 2\frac{n(n-1)n}{2}-2\frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}$$

Comment: Set $L=l-1$ (so that $l=L+1$)in the first sum so you are summing from $L=1$ to $L=n-1$. Take out the factor $2$ which applies to every term in the sum, and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on **@Yves'** answer, there's two useful ways to rearrange sums.

1. Shift the index by $k$. You can show that this is true by writing out the terms. I've swapped your index $l$ for $i$ and given a general first term, $a$ and general terms $x_i$. 
   $$\begin{aligned}\sum_{i=a}^nx_i&\quad=\quad\sum_{i=a+k}^{n+k}{x_{\color{red}{i}-k}}\\x_a+x_{a+1}+\ldots+x_n
   &\quad=\quad x_{(\color{red}{a+k}-k)}+x_{(\color{red}{a+k+1}-k)}+\ldots+x_{(\color{red}{n+k}-k)}\end{aligned}$$
2. Expand the sum and use the formulae for [sums of powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Sums_of_powers). It's not a bad idea to have the formulae for $\sum i$, $\sum i^2$ and $\sum i^3$ memorised, since they're useful and quite brief.

I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you kind sir that helped me solve the problem, may god bless you with a bunch of kids.

Answer (score 0):

The first transformation is easy, just a shift of $l$ by $1$.

The second uses the triangular and pyramidal numbers (sum of integers and sum of squared integers).